# oracle database vs mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, insert-update

I m planning to move our DB from Oracle to mySql. But have 2qus on mind:-

1- MYsql  will take how much time to inser/update 20   20 concurrent requests (users) with  50,000 database transactions/request  i.e Time taken to insert/update - 20*50000 records.

2- Time taken to insert 1.5 million records  to Data Store (Say we index all documents in 1 batch )

Comment: How often do you need to "insert 1.5M rows"?  That sounds like a 1-time action that should not matter in the long run.  Please provide the schema (Oracle or MySQL) so that we can understand the 'index' you mention.

Comment: Just tested batch inserting 560K rows a with a simple table, oracle is 25x times faster than mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad to answer, but let me give you some tips if you do move to MySQL.

- Use batches of 100 rows in single `INSERTs`, or (even better), use LOAD DATA.  Single-row `INSERTs` have a lot of overhead.
- When having multiple concurrent actions happening, it is better to keep transactions 'short'.  Use explicit `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` to be clear what you are calling a transaction.
- Rethink your schema/application if you are often changing 50K rows at once.  Often this implies redundant data that should be kept 1 place, not 50K places.
- UUID indexes are inefficient.